# Integrating React Router with Unstated

Tags: react-router-v4, unstated

The following code, where each component includes `<Subscribe to={[ZebraContainer]}>` causes ZebraContainer to be constructed three times.  Is there an accepted pattern to maintain ZebraContainer as a global singleton and only construct once?

```
  <Provider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">

        ...

        <Route path="/foo" component={Foo} />
        <Route path="/bar" component={Bar} />
        <Route path="/baz" component={Baz} />

      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

In unstated containers ARE singletons. They aren't reconstructed when the components rerender.